# Rebind gridview with updated row ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in ASP.nET and I have a "Select" command field.  What I want to do is that when the user click on on the "select", I would like to take the selected row and do some calculations and rebind the original gridview with updated the row.

How can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Call `GridView.DataBind()` again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView not Rebinding Properly After Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759325/gridview-not-rebinding-properly-after-postback)

Answer (score 2):

```
// do your thingy

DataGridViewName.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of places where grabbing the row is already explained. Take a look at this [Link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jun/07/GridView-and-CommandArguments). You have to call the bind data method on the grid after your calculations. If you want to modify just that row, I would think you modify the source data collection for that row and rebind.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) may also help. Instead of Edit, you could have Select.